# Using vmprof from within script

Tags: python, profiling, pypy

To profile a function one can use:

```
import cProfile
print cProfile.run('foo()')
```

Is it possible to use [vmprof](http://vmprof.readthedocs.io/) in similar way, i.e. just to profile one function from within the code? I'm asking because the linked docs only shows how to run it from command line:

```
python -m vmprof <program.py> <program parameters>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do import vmprof; vmprof.enable(); vmprof.disable() Details are here: http://vmprof.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#api

Comment: Thanks! But there it says `fileno` in `vmprof.enable()`, I assume it means it needs a file-like object to write to, so it can later display the statistics with `vmprof.read_profile()`, isn't it possible to just print it (to stdout), like with the cProfiler example above?

Comment: the print-to-stdout is generally discouraged (you should rather use the web view)